# An error occurred while connecting to the server:The Autodiscover service couldn't be located. While making Web-addin in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Thank you first.
Hi, I'm making a web add-in in Visual Studio for Outlook, but while trying to run the for the first time it's throwing the following error.

Error   An error occurred while connecting to the server:

```
    The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.
```

I really need help with this. I didn't find anything on the internet that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to enable Modern Authentication on your O365 tenant. See [Basic Authentication and Exchange Online – February 2021 Update](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-february-2021-update/ba-p/2111904) for more information.

Also you may find the [Enable or disable modern authentication for Outlook in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/enable-or-disable-modern-authentication-in-exchange-online#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Microsoft%20365%20admin,Windows%20and%20later%20(recommended).) article helpful.

Comment: Did it help? Do you still get the error message?